# devart ssis mysql data flow

Tags: ssis, devart

I have a data flow from excel to mysql database, and the destination table keeps giving the same error. I have reinstalled visual studio and ssis devart components still I get the same error even if I create a new project in visual studio. I even changed the source of data but still same problem appears.Please help. Below is the error message.

```
Error: 0x0 at Data Flow Task, Devart MySql Destination: An exception has occurred during data processing, the message returned from the provider is:
Unknown column 'program_version_id' in 'field list'
Error: 0xC0047062 at Data Flow Task, Devart MySql Destination [38]: System.Exception: An exception has occurred during data processing, the message returned from the provider is:
Unknown column 'program_version_id' in 'field list' ---> Devart.Data.MySql.bb: Unknown column 'program_version_id' in 'field list'
   at Devart.Data.MySql.bs.v()
   at Devart.Data.MySql.bs.f()
   at Devart.Data.MySql.cm.a(aa[]& A_0, Int32& A_1, Boolean A_2)
   at Devart.Data.MySql.cm.kt(Byte[] A_0, Int32 A_1, Boolean A_2, String A_3)
   at Devart.Data.MySql.bh.j()
   at Devart.Data.MySql.bh.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Devart.Data.MySql.bh.iw()
   at Devart.SSIS.Common.DestinationComponentBase.c.a()
   at Devart.SSIS.Common.PipelineComponentBase.FailoverCall[T](Func`1 call)
   at Devart.SSIS.Common.DestinationComponentBase.a(PipelineBuffer A_0, IDTSInput100 A_1)
   at Devart.SSIS.Common.DestinationComponentBase.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Devart.SSIS.Common.DestinationComponentBase.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostProcessInput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Int32 inputID, IDTSBuffer100 pDTSBuffer, IntPtr bufferWirePacket)
Error: 0xC0047022 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Devart MySql Destination" (38) failed with error code 0x80131500 while processing input "input" (49). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Information: 0x40043008 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043009 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
Task failed: Data Flow Task
```

Comment: Can you show the configuration of `Devart MySql Destination` data flow component?

Comment: Do you mean the connection parameters to the database?

Comment: No, not the connection parameters. I'm referring to the configuration of the destination task, part of which contains column mappings. The error you posted suggests a column mapping issue, or a missing column. Your question is lacking details to help with remote troubleshooting. Any further information you can provide about the data Source, and configuration of data Destination would help us help you.

Comment: I have managed to correct the problems and its a kind of hack. All i had to do was go to the database delete the table giving errors and then re-generate the database table and all worked fine after that, same thing happened again on another table after deleting a link table and had to do the same process. Some how all table names and their foreign keys are stored somewhere, even if you rebuild your project in visual studio those parameters are kept.

Comment: When the schema is changed next time, please open your package in Visual Studio and press the Refresh button in Advanced Editor for Devart MySql Destination. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Tried many things including the refresh button on the Devart advanced Editor as Devart suggested above.

The only thing I found to get the Devart tool to work was to edit the SSIS Connection Manager, Advanced tab and change the "Refresh Metadata" parameter (in the Caching section) to "True".